# SecTrustEvaluate failure because of certificate validity

Tags: ios, certificate, ios13

We are using the self-signed certificate at the server end. When our iOS App tries to evaluate the certificate, due to new regulations forced upon https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210176, it fails by giving `"recoverableTrustFailure"`. The reason being the validity of certificate being > 825 days. 
The API used for the call is `SecTrustEvaluateWithError(_:_:)`.

Although we can ignore this particular error, we would not like to since there can be many other reasons for the error which could cause security vulnerabilities.

Any leads for how can one avoid this validity enforcement/make sure the API doesn't give this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the best course of action is to re-issue your certificate with a more reasonable expiration date

Comment: @Paulw11: that will be the last option that we need to do. Thanks though.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?